# Changing method of signing application on Android Studio

Tags: android, batch-file, gradle, apksigner

I have a key to sign my applications on format `.dat`. The only way that I have of sign my applications on right way is using  `apksigner.bat`, the default method set on Android Studio don't work. There is a way to change the method of sign for use the `apksigner.bat` inside of `gradle.build`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem adding one more task o pos-build of `gradle` process calling a `.bat` script that perform the sign process.